# Rails 5: Creating an object with a belongs_to association that belongs_to user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Working on my first rails app and I'm stuck. I've tried really hard to solve this myself, but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm having trouble making an object that belongs_to an object that belongs_to user.

These are the Models association structure:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :destroy

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :docs, dependent: :destroy

class Doc < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project
```

I think I need to somehow reference the project that the doc I'm trying to build belongs to, but I'm stuck. If I add a hidden_field_tag to the doc form to pass in the project_id, then use a param in the docs controller to assign @project to that project_id, this works, but I know there's a better way than sending in a hidden_field_tag...

Any ideas on what to research or a solution here? I feel like I'm missing something really basic!

Comment: I can get the code to work by changing two things: 1, adding a hidden_field_tag on my sheets form to pass on the project_id, and 2, adding this code in my sheets create function:     @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])     . However, there's got to be a better way than with hidden_field, right?

Comment: The 2nd way is what followed usually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there is probably a more standard use case sort of answer, the following worked for me.

I created a new column in the user table to store an integer in active_project to reference the project's id. When making a doc, I first set @project to the project with the id of current_user.active_project, then create the doc as belonging to the @project.

This may be a little backwards, but it works, and I can use the active_project data to allow users to revisit their last project open login. Thanks @pavan for the suggestions, they set me down the right path! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the form which you are using to create sheet (if that page has access to @project , may be show.html.erb of projects)

```
form_for([@project, @project.sheets.build]) do |f|
#rest of the code
end
```

If the form does not have access to @project then
In new action of Sheets controller

```
@project = Project.find(params[:project_id]) #using data from params hash
@sheet = @project.sheets.build
```

and in form to create sheet

```
form_for([@project, @sheet]) do |f|
end
```

In create action of sheets controller

```
 @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
 #rest of the code what you have
```

Comment: The form is in a shared partial, being rendered on project page. Updating the form_for section resulted in error. Finding project by :project_id returns error: couldn't find project without ID.  However, adding a hidden_field_tag to pass in project_id on form works when adding a line of code to the create function. Can you think of a better way?

Comment: Please post your project page which renders partial and form partial of sheets. This might help